# Mod rewrite to remove a directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'm running a PHP web app that has a `.htaccess` file as below.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

It works perfectly, but Google is attempting to browse our URL and look for `http://www.website.com.au/questions/1234/question-name` when actually they're hosted at `http://www.website.com.au/1234/question-name` (remove the `/questions/`)

What do I need to add to this `.htaccess` file to remove the /questions/?

I came up with this, but for some reason it's generating a 500 server error when I add it below `RewriteRule` and before `</IfModule>`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /questions/
RewriteRule ^questions/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Why are these two rules not working?

Comment: Nevermind. My bad! Solved it. I'd post the solution to share for posterity but I don't have enough rep on the site to do it yet! Doh. :)